# Find and replace String in elasticSearch using loop

Tags: elasticsearch

i need help with finding and replacing a string from all the indexes and replace it with another string. I wanna change my attribut libelle when his value is 'Vol, Incendie' to 'Vol et incendie'.
here is my elasticJson example :

```
"devisdata": [
    {
        "nameWhoMadeIt": " ADMIN admin",
        "Garanties": [
            {
                "libelle": "Vol, incendie",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "libelle": "bdg",
                "id": 2
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "nameWhoMadeIt": " ADMIN admin",
        "Garanties": [
            {
                "libelle": "Vol, incendie",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "libelle": "bdg",
                "id": 2
            },
        ]
    },
]
}
```

and here is my request :

```
 {
   "script": {
   "source": "for (int i=0; i <= ctx._source.devisdata.length; i++) { 
               for (int j=0; j <= ctx._source.devisdata[i].Garanties.length; j++) { 
                if(ctx._source.devisdata[i].Garanties[j].libelle == 'Vol, Incendie') {
                 ctx._source.devisdata[i].Garanties[j].libelle = params.value; break
                } 
               }
             }",
  "lang": "painless",
   "params": {
   "value": "Vol et incendie"
     }
   }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, i just went out of the array. i only needed to do < not <=.
is there a better way to do this without looping ??